# Merging of clusters

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I have a matrix that describe objects in groups.

```
n <- 6 # number of objects
group <- matrix(c(1,2,1,4,1,3,6,3,5,3,NA,NA,2,NA,2,NA,NA,6,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,5),5,6)
colnames(group) <- colnames(group, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "obj.")
rownames(group) <- rownames(group, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "step.")
group #  an n-1 by n matrix
#        obj.1 obj.2 obj.3 obj.4 obj.5 obj.6
# step.1     1     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
# step.2     2     6    NA    NA    NA    NA
# step.3     1     3     2     6    NA    NA
# step.4     4     5    NA    NA    NA    NA
# step.5     1     3     2     6     4     5
```

I want create a matrix with merging of clusters at step. This matrix is equal to object merge returned in *hclust* function.

```
merge <- matrix(c(-1, -2, 1, -4, 3, -3, -6, 2, -5, 4), 5, 2)
merge
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   -1   -3
# [2,]   -2   -6
# [3,]    1    2
# [4,]   -4   -5
# [5,]    3    4
```

> merge is an n-1 by 2 matrix. Row i of merge describes the merging of clusters at step i of the clustering. If an element j in the row is negative, then observation -j was merged at this stage. If j is positive then the merge was with the cluster formed at the (earlier) stage j of the algorithm. Thus negative entries in merge indicate agglomerations of singletons, and positive entries indicate agglomerations of non-singletons.

I have not been able to find a simple solution. Is there any function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have a set of groups (one per row)...

```
group
#        obj.1 obj.2 obj.3 obj.4 obj.5 obj.6
# step.1     1     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
# step.2     2     6    NA    NA    NA    NA
# step.3     1     3     2     6    NA    NA
# step.4     4     5    NA    NA    NA    NA
# step.5     1     3     2     6     4     5
```

... and you want to know which two previous rows were merged to form the current row.

I would start by creating a matrix that indicates whether each object is in a particular row:

```
(hasObs <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(group)), function(i) rowSums(!is.na(group) & group == i)))
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# step.1    1    0    1    0    0    0
# step.2    0    1    0    0    0    1
# step.3    1    1    1    0    0    1
# step.4    0    0    0    1    1    0
# step.5    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I would use this to create a matrix where each element (i,j) indicates the most recent previous row (before i) at which j appeared (or -j if there is no such previous row):

```
(prevObs <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(hasObs)), function(i) {
  pos <- which(head(hasObs, -1)[,i] == 1)
  rep(c(-i, pos), diff(c(0, pos, nrow(hasObs))))
}))
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#          -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6
# step.1    1   -2    1   -4   -5   -6
# step.1    1    2    1   -4   -5    2
# step.3    3    3    3   -4   -5    3
# step.3    3    3    3    4    4    3
```

Now it is easy to determine which rows were merged to make the current row:

```
t(apply(hasObs*prevObs, 1, function(x) unique(x[x != 0])))
#        [,1] [,2]
# step.1   -1   -3
# step.2   -2   -6
# step.3    1    2
# step.4   -4   -5
# step.5    3    4
```

The first row combined individual elements 1 and 3, the next combined individual elements 2 and 6, the third combined the first two groups, the fourth combined individual elements 4 and 5, and the fifth row combined the groups from rows 3 and 4.